# Converting a downloaded file to base64 using https.request

Tags: node.js, base64

I'm trying to download an image, and get it in base64. This is what I've been using so far:

```
let base64Data = 'data:' + file.mimetype + ';base64,';
const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
    res.on('data', (d) => {
        const buffer = new Buffer(d).toString('base64');
        base64Data += buffer;
    });

    res.on('end', () => {
        console.log(base64Data);
    });
});

req.end();
```

The file gets downloaded, but the base64Data is malformed.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` may fire more than once, which means you need to collect all the chunks of data and combine and Base64-encode them in the `end` handler (as concatenating separate Base64-encoded strings may not yield the original value when decoded):

```
const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  let chunks = [];

  res.on('data', (d) => {
    chunks.push(d);
  });

  res.on('end', () => {
    const buffer = Buffer.concat(chunks).toString('base64');
    base64Data += buffer;
    console.log(base64Data);
  });
});
```